# Normalizing/unaccenting text in Java

Tags: java, text, character, normalize

How can I normalize/unaccent text in Java? I am currently using java.text.Normalizer:

```
Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    .replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "")
```

But it is far from perfect. For example, it leaves Norwegian characters æ and ø untouched. Does anyone know of an alternative? I am looking for something that would convert characters in all sorts of languages to just the a-z range. I realize there are different ways to do this (e.g. should æ be encoded as 'a', 'e' or even 'ae'?) and I'm open for any solution. I prefer to not write something myself since I think it's unlikely that I will be able to do this well for all languages. Performance is NOT critical.

The use case: I want to convert a user entered name to a plain a-z ranged name. The converted name will be displayed to the user, so I want it to match as close as possible what the user wrote in his original language.

**EDIT:**

Alright people, thanks for negging the post and not addressing my question, yay! :) Maybe I should have left out the use case. But please allow me to clarify. I need to convert the name in order to store it internally. **I have no control over the choice of letters allowed here.** The name will be visible to the user in, for example, the URL. The same way that your user name on this forum is normalized and shown to you in the URL if you click on your name. This forum converts a name like "Bășan" to "baan" and a name like "Øyvind" to "yvind". I believe it can be done better. I am looking for ideas and preferably a library function to do this for me. I know I can not get it right, I know that "o" and "ø" are different, etc, but if my name is "Øyvind" and I register on an online forum, I would likely prefer that my user name is "oyvind" and not "yvind". Hope that this makes any sense! Thanks!

(And NO, we will not allow the user to pick his own user name. I am really just looking for an alternative to java.text.Normalizer. Thanks!)

Comment: Many languages (such as Norwegian as in your example) have characters that are *different* from the Latin a-z range. ø is not just an o with a slash through it (and the slash is *not* optional). Why not show the user their proper name, instead of a mangled version?

Comment: You can't convert all names to a-z.  Annabel-Sue cannot be converted because it has a hyphen.  Names in other alphabets such as Cyrillic, Greek, Perso-Arabic cannot be trivially converted to the Roman alphabet.  I don't know why you're trying to do this, but imposing structure on people's names is rarely the right way to do things.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want this to be a discussion whether I should normalize the text or not. I'm storing and showing the user his original name when possible, but the normalized version is still displayed in some situations. Heck, this site does the same. If your stackoverflow name is "Bășan", your user name here will be "baan". This name is visible to you and anyone else through your profile. I'm not familiar with Romanian, but would guess that "basan" would have been a better transliteration? Hyphens, apostrophes, etc would probably just have to go. I'm looking for a tool to do this for me.

Comment: Could you give some insight to the curious about why you are limited and how? I assume by a-z range, you're making reference to the (American) English alphabet. We deal with similar issues at work in text mining. Proteins with names like HIF1-alpha are spelled in many different ways including use of Greek characters, etc.

Comment: Sure, see the bolded text I added in my OP. This is not a weekend project I'm hacking together, it's a large system and 'a-z' and '0-9' is unfortunately all that it supports. Now, we wish to import names and turn them into valid user names supported by our system. Your question is like asking the gmail team why they only allow digits, numbers and periods in their user names. **Please trust me, we know the implications of what we are doing and only need help with the question in the OP.** I thought giving the use case would be helpful but dearly wish I hadn't.

Comment: By the way, as for Chinese, Arabic, etc names, these people transliterate their names themselves already when they entered them so _in our specific case_ this will not be a problem. And thanks for the language lesson Greg. I am Scandinavian and fluent in Norwegian and Swedish, but it's always helpful to have a Kiwi teach me about my language, hehe :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to presume. As I'm sure you realise, there's no *simple* answer for this kind of question and most of the time a better approach is "don't do that". Perhaps you could empirically build up a translation table, logging whenever a user-entered character doesn't have an appropriate translation. When a new unknown character is found, decide on an appropriate translation and add it to the table.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have considering ALL of the implications of what you're doing, ALL the ways it can go wrong, what you'll do when you get Chinese pictograms and other things that have no equivalent in the Latin Alphabet...

There's not a library that I know of that does what you want. If you have a list of equivalencies (as you say, the 'æ' to 'ae' or whatever), you could store them in a file (or, if you're doing this a lot, in a sorted array in memory, for performance reason) and then do a lookup and replace by character. If you have the space in memory to store the (# of unicode characters) as a char array, being able to run through the unicode values of each character and do a straight lookup would be the most efficient.

i.e., /u1234 => lookupArray[1234] => 'q'

or whatever.

so you'll have a loop that looks like:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
  buf.append(lookupArray[Character.unicodeValue(string.charAt(i))]);
}
```

I wrote that from scratch, so there are probably some bad method calls or something.

You'll have to do something to handle  decomposed characters, probably with a lookahead buffer.

Good luck - I'm sure this is fraught with pitfalls.

Comment: you can also just use a map and do a string.replace(...). Like everyone, I am slightly worried about such replacements because there always is an element of unknown (characters that you did not foresee!).

Comment: The map/string.replace was the first thing I though of too, but for performance reasons I figured that would be a lot slower. String.replace() is going to be O(N) in the size of the string, and the map lookups are whatever the big O is there (naively, I think it's O(M), in the size of the elements of the map). 

Doing array lookups is O(1), and building the string buffer is O(1) amortized, so it will be *much* faster, over long strings and the impossibly large mapping this would require to handle every unicode character.

Comment: Thanks Kane for focusing on the question! Yeah I considered your approach and I think it's the most efficient way to do things. As I noted in my OP and as others note as well, I am not so keen on using this approach since I will definitely miss things or transliterate things incorrectly in languages I am not so familiar with. If I don't find a better way, it's what I might end up doing though.